# Laravel 5.3: Migrate step by step

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, migration, database-migration

I was wondering if it was possible to migrate migrations one by one in Laravel 5.3.

I can't get the `--step` option working and documention only mention this option to be used with the `rollback` or the `refresh` command.

```
// this works
php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1
// this doesn't work
php artisan migrate --step=1
```

Thank you, have a nice day

Comment: is `--step` actually meant to work like that migrating a database? I thought it was *just* for rollbacks?

Comment: @AndyHolmes is correct, your migration files don't have step numbers assigned to them. When you run `migrate` artisan finds any migrations that haven't been ran, it then runs them as a batch and assigns a step number at that time when it adds them to the `migrations` db table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official way to run migrations one by one as there is typically no need to, as it is the ease of them adding simultaneously that is a benefit to laravel.

The `--step=x` is used only when rolling back migrations.

If you did want to run migrations one by one they way to achieve this would be to add them one by to the project running `php artisan migrate` each time.

I hope this helped, comment if there is anything else you need or that is not clear.

Comment: You can also add a `die()` or `exit()` in the beginning of the migration file where you want to stop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run migrations one-by-one, you might try the following:

```
( \
  mkdir migrations-tmp; \
  for i in database/migrations/[0-9]*.php; do \
    echo `basename $i`:; \
    cp -a $i migrations-tmp/ && \
    php artisan migrate --force --path `pwd`/migrations-tmp --pretend -vvvv; \
    rm -f migrations-tmp/*; \
  done \
); \
rm -rf migrations-tmp
```

Explanation:

- make a temporary directory
- for every migration file

  - output its name
  - copy the migration file to the temporary directory
  - execute this single migration by specifying the path to the migration files
  - remove the migration file from the temporary directory
- remove the temporary directory

Comment: Good suggestion for run migrations one-by-one... I was looking for something like this ... thanks!